# What does ビー means in this sentence?

Tags: slang

鼻から、デロデロ、ビー！

I heard デロデロ is 'soggy' or 'drunk/intoxicated',

so that means something soggy from the nose... Is it a snot?

And what is ビー?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think it's a snot, nasal discharge.

デロデロ means soggy and slimy. It's a kind of onomatopoeic expression.

ビー is also an onomatopoeic expression, which means something appears in a rush and with a large content.

鼻から、デロデロ、ビー！　means "A lot of slimy snot is coming from the nose fast and furiously."

Hope this helps!

edit)
There is another interpretation which is more likely:

鼻から、出ろ出ろ、ビー
"Hey, Mr.Snot, you should go out from the nose. Go!"
It is said by a mother to her child.

[image]

Comment: 自信はありませんが、デロデロは「（鼻水さん）出ろ！出ろ！」ではないでしょうか。*I don't have confidence, but Derodero means 
"Hey nasal mucus, get out of there!"*

Comment: おお、そうかもしれません。っていうか、そうじゃないかと私も今思います。編集します。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 「ゼノギアス」っていうゲームの中のセリフみたいですよ…「ゲゲッ、チョキか？
チョキなのか！？
うぎゃー、ま、負けたあ！
なんてこったあ！！
鼻から、デロデロ、ビー！」だそうです　http://xenodd.xxxxxxxx.jp/memory/npc01.html

Comment: That's right, it's from 'Xenogears'.

Comment: @Guest: つづくセリフの「オー・マイ・ガブリーヌ！」を見ると、面白そうな言い回しの振り替えのようですね。真剣に考える内容ではありませんが、出自（出典）の性質が分かると色々考えられます。「鼻から、鼻血がブー」、「鼻から、鼻血がドバドバ」、「鼻から、鼻水ド～ロド～ロ」と「いないいないバー」との合作。作者はきっと「鼻水吸引」より汚いイメージをもって書いていますね。ＯＰさん「鼻から、デロデロ、ビー！」は単なる音遊びですので日本語の意味は特にありません。

Comment: @mackygoo: 画像をアップしていただき、ありがとうございます。大変わかりやすくなったと思います。

Comment: ＠ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ　＆　＠Guest：context and backgroundの情報をいただきありがとうございます。

Comment: ＠Guest：情報ありがとうございます。私も鼻血なら「ブー」という擬音語が定番だけどなって思っていました。言葉あそびを解釈するのはナンセンスかも知れませんが、「デロデロ」が「ドロドロ」なのか「出ろ出ろ」なのかに興味があります。（両者の掛け言葉、という解釈ですよね。）ゲームの登場人物は子供でしょうか、大人でしょうか？

Comment: @Seesawscene: Sorry for the late response. He's an adult, a man obsessed with rock-paper-scissors game. If you win against him five times in a row he will give you RPS Badge. He say this phrase "うぎゃー、ま、負けたあ！なんてこったあ！！鼻から、デロデロ、ビー！" after one of his defeats.